# Have + Present Perfect Continuous

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive, continuous

Doing some tasks in the textbook I stumbled across one sentence.
Here is a small dialog.

> Do you have a headache ?
>
> Yes, I've had a headache all morning.

Why do we use the present perfect tense here, but not the pres. perf. continuous ?
My logic is that we have an indicator for a period of time (`all morning`) and `have` is a part of the set phrase (`have a headache`), which is the reason why `have` can be used in continuous context.
But still, we use the present perfect tense. Although `I've been having a headache all morning` sounds weird for me.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: What does that small dialog do? In other words, what is the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb "have" already provides the "continuous" sense. It describes a state, and not an action

So we tend to say

> I have a headache.

and  not

> (?) I am having a headache.

(This latter in grammatically correct, but sounds odd. As if is something the speaker can turn off if they chose)

So when we put that into a perfect form (to describe the state starting at some time in the past) No continuous tense is used.

You could use a continuous tense for *repeated* headaches over a period of time

> I've been having headaches once or twice a week for the last six months.

Comment: Ok, thanks 
It's clear for me now